# Mobile app for an existing not mobile website

Tags: android, mobile, web

I wan't to build an app which will work like the facebook app or the 9GAG app, the app need to acces the website content and show it inside the app, I don't have acces to the website I want to build the app on, does any one know how to do that?

Comment: You mean how to parse website html?

Comment: The site should expose some kind of api to do what you would like. If this is not the case you would probably want to have a web view container where you can surf the site... but this is much more like having a browser and doing "normal" surfing.

Comment: i guess i need to parse a website

Answer (score 0):

The website must provide some kind of  public or private API to fetch the content as feed. Then only we can integrate and show in the app. For example you can see the Feedly Android App,it fetches the content of the news,blog websites and showing in the app. Market url : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.devhd.feedly